# OperationalError: no such table on some ManyToManyFields only

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website with product and user models, and i wanted to create multiple ManyToMany fields to User model (Products purchased, sold, etc).
When i added the first cart ManyToManyField on User model and tried this in shell:

```
User.objects.get(username="root").cart.all()
```

It worked perfectly fine and outputted query set of all objects of User's cart.

But then i added other 3 ManyToManyFields to User model:

```
items_purchased = models.ManyToManyField("Product", related_name="items_purchased")
items_sold = models.ManyToManyField("Product", related_name="items_sold")
items_listed = models.ManyToManyField("Product", related_name="items_listed")
```

However, once i checked latest fields:

```
User.objects.get(username="root").items_purchased.all()
```

I got an error:

```
OperationalError: no such table: Home_user_items_purchased
```

---

What i tried:

- I made migrations and have synced them to database.
- I deleted every
  migration files except **init** and 0001.
- I tried to migrate
  migration files seperately in application.

Is there any way that i can fix this problem without clearing out whole database? Could this be Django's problem or have i done something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Creating and running the migrations should have created the necessary tables. Deleting the migrations and starting with a new database is the easiest approach. We don't know the current database schema or migration contents. Even with that information, syncing up the database schema with the migrations could be tricky.

Comment: How `User` object relate to `items_purchased` ? It is related to `Product` NO ?

Comment: @itzmeontv items_purchased is field in User(model.Model) and it is just related with Product(model.Model). Does related_name have something to do with Product fields?

Comment: @Alasdair I have deleted migrations but they didn't seem to change anything, Is clearing out database last option?

Comment: Deleting the migrations that have been run without starting with a fresh database is a bad idea. Now the database and the migrations are out of sync. We don't have enough information to tell you how to fix up the database manually, so starting afresh is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Alasdair Should i use `python manage.py flush`? This will only delete model data correct?

Comment: No, `flush` will only drop the data. I'm suggesting you drop and recreate the database. How to do this depends on the database you are using.

Comment: @Alasdair I am currently using `sqllite` but only models are dependent on database right?

Comment: For sqlite you can just remove the file (or rename it to something else if you need to save the data). Django will create a new database file when you run migrate. I do not understand your question 'only models are dependent on database'.

Comment: There is problem with migrations in django, when you delete them it can pass makemigrations command on that app. Lets say your app name where you have User model is common. Then you should execute `python manage.py makemigrations common` to directly check that model again. Most times it solves problem.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks, problem was solved by resetting db!

Comment: @EminMastizada It didn't solve the problem though, I even tried to migrate every other migration seperately: `python manage.py migrate Home 0002`. However, resetting database seemed to be consequential.